# Why are image flex items behaving differently in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning flexbox and how flex items are laid inside the flex container with their initial width being flex-basis and then shrunk and grown when there is negative and positive space respectively. However, when I tried this in practice I see differences in how it works across two browsers - Firefox and Chrome when the flex items are images .

Suppose I want two flex items which are images(700px and 900px wide) in two equal columns inside a centered flex container with max-width:960px.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p> Two Images side by side , overflows in Chrome but shrinks in Firefox </p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/700/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/900/300" alt="">
</div>
```

```
<p> Two  Images side by side , overflows in Chrome but shrinks in Firefox </p>
<div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/700/300" alt="">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/900/300" alt="">
 </div>
```

In Firefox they work how I expected them to be. The flex images each with base size: 960 px ( image width = 100% of the width of the flex container ) and then are shrunk to 480px each . However, in Chrome images are with their intrinsic width ( 700 and 900 px) and overflowing the flex container ( image width 100% of the parent flex container doesnt work ). Also, in the Chrome Inspector  if I hover over the flex container I see the overflowing area of the flex container being shaded

[image]
[image]

I'd previously learned the shaded portion for flex containers shows the white space available for items to grow when their width: max-content. So, I really dot understand why the overflowed area in the flex container is showing up as shaded in this case as I can't think of items growing to that space.

I learned ([Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)) that you can fix this by setting the min-width for images to something like 0

```
img {
min-wdth : 0px 
}
```

This CSS does make Chome behave like Firefox in displaying the flex boxes but I am not sure why. What I understood from the Stackoverflow answer is for images the min-width = min-content is the intrinsic size of the images and as such it can't shrink below that. However, what doesn't make sense to me is why the width of the images doesnt increase (to the parent flex container width of 960px) when they each have a width of 100% since it is more than min-width = min-content of images(960 px > 700px or 900px ) and why for one browser you need to add min-width:0px and for the other it's not needed.

Comment: by default flex-wrap is set to nowrap and flex-shrink is equal to 1 so the image are obliged to stay at the same row and will shrink to fit that space. The min-width constraint is what prevent this shriniking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images as flex items are notoriously quirky. They will render differently across different browsers. The solution, which seems to work reliably and consistently across all broswers, is to wrap the images in a container, such as a `div`. This makes the container the flex item. This removes the images from a *flex formatting context* and returns them to a *block formatting context*.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top; /* remove descendere space */
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><!-- new wrapper -->
    <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/700/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div><!-- new wrapper -->
    <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/900/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```